# How to extract zipcode in the middle of a string?

Tags: python, regex

Here is an address:

```
address = "35 rue de trucmuche, 75009 PARIS"
```

I want to extract the zipcode (`75009`) in the address using a Regex.

I tried this:

```
reg = re.compile('^.*(P<zipcode>\d{5}).*$')
match = reg.match(address)
match.groupdict().zipcode # should be 75009
```

I get a:

`AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'groupdict'`

I think my Regex is wrong. I can't understand why.

Comment: Why not use `reg = re.compile('\d{5}')` with `reg.findall(address)`?

Comment: There is no 'trucmuche' street in the 9e arr.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are just missing the ? in the named capturing group:

```
^.*(?P<zipcode>\d{5}).*$
```

---

```
reg = re.compile('^.*(?P<zipcode>\d{5}).*$')
match = reg.match(address)
match.groupdict().zipcode # should be 75009
```

Answer (score 4):

A named capture group in Python must start with `?`:

```
>>> import re
>>> address = "35 rue de trucmuche, 75009 PARIS"
>>> re.match('^.*(?P<zipcode>\d{5}).*$', address).groupdict()['zipcode']
'75009'
```

Otherwise, you will be trying to match the literal text `P<zipcode>`.

---

Also, the `.groupdict()` method returns a normal Python dictionary:

```
>>> type(re.match('^.*(?P<zipcode>\d{5}).*$', address).groupdict())
<class 'dict'>
```

This means that you will need to access the zipcode value as `dct['zipcode']`, not `dct.zipcode`.

Answer (score 0):

Your regex is wrong. That is why it won't match, it returns `None`, and complains that `None` doesn't have a `groupdict()`.

In fact there are two mistakes as far as I can see.

```
reg = re.compile('^.*(?P<zipcode>\d{5}).*$')
```

------------------------------------^---------------------
(needs a '?' in front of 'P')

and the other mistake that will come up is that `groupdict()` nees to be accessed like a normal `dict`, that is

```
match.groupdict()['zipcode']
```

You should probably also put a check to see that the match matches, e.g.

```
if match:
     match.groupdict()['zipcode']
```

as according to https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#match-objects the match object will return `True` if it exists.